# Choosing the right firmware version to upgrade wireless router

Tags: router

I have a Linksys WRT54G router with firmware v8.00.8. When I visited the Linksys [support website](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/support/routers/WRT54G) trying to download new firmware update, I saw an option to "select hardware version." In that drop down, 8.0, 8,1, and 8,2 are all available. Should I selected 8.2 to download because it's the latest one or should I download the 8.0 because my firmware is v8.00.8? This is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must select the actual hardware version that matches your router. It's written on the bottom of the router, but your existing firmware suggests your hardware version is `8.0`. Firmware meant for a newer hardware version will not work.